# materialize_css__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Carousel is not a constructor

Tags: angular, materialize

I am getting a similar error, with Carousel:

TypeError: materialize_css__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Carousel is not a constructor

Can you share how this issue got resolved for you? My environment -

material-css npm library 0.100.2 is installed.

In angular.json (using angular 6) : Scripts:

```
  "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "./node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js",
  "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js",
```

Css:

```
  "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css",              
  "src/styles.css"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? What's the context?

Comment: I am trying to create an angular project with materialize-css. When trying to create javascript object like Carousel, this error is occuring.